# Insert text in nested list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this library `chips_choice` to show the text by fetching the api. The data i'm getting from the api is "A", "B". But i want to insert a new text "All" in `DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales` in `name` a nested list. The result i want to display after inserting "All" text will be "All", "A", "B". Below is the model and dart code till now what i have tried.

> Model

```
class DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  String? lang;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? dishTypeId;

  DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.lang,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.dishTypeId,
  });
  DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    name = json["name"]?.toString();
    lang = json["lang"]?.toString();
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    dishTypeId = json["dishTypeId"]?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["name"] = name;
    data["lang"] = lang;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    data["dishTypeId"] = dishTypeId;
    return data;
  }
}

class DishMenuTypesDishTypes {
  String? id;
  bool? isDeleted;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  List<DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales?>? dishTypesLocales;

  DishMenuTypesDishTypes({
    this.id,
    this.isDeleted,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.dishTypesLocales,
  });
  DishMenuTypesDishTypes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json["id"]?.toString();
    isDeleted = json["is_deleted"];
    createdAt = json["createdAt"]?.toString();
    updatedAt = json["updatedAt"]?.toString();
    if (json["dish_types_locales"] != null) {
      final v = json["dish_types_locales"];
      final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(DishMenuTypesDishTypesDishTypesLocales.fromJson(v));
      });
      dishTypesLocales = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = id;
    data["is_deleted"] = isDeleted;
    data["createdAt"] = createdAt;
    data["updatedAt"] = updatedAt;
    if (dishTypesLocales != null) {
      final v = dishTypesLocales;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());
      });
      data["dish_types_locales"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class DishMenuTypes {
  String? message;
  List<DishMenuTypesDishTypes?>? DishTypes;

  DishMenuTypes({
    this.message,
    this.DishTypes,
  });
  DishMenuTypes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json["message"]?.toString();
    if (json["DishTypes"] != null) {
      final v = json["DishTypes"];
      final arr0 = <DishMenuTypesDishTypes>[];
      v.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(DishMenuTypesDishTypes.fromJson(v));
      });
      DishTypes = arr0;
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["message"] = message;
    if (DishTypes != null) {
      final v = DishTypes;
      final arr0 = [];
      v!.forEach((v) {
        arr0.add(v!.toJson());
      });
      data["DishTypes"] = arr0;
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

> Dart

```
    Widget buildDishMenuTypes(List<DishMenuTypesDishTypes> data) {
    data.insert(
            0, new DishMenuTypesDishTypes(dishTypesLocales: )); //Here trying to add "All"
    return Container(
    child:ChoiceChip(
label: Text(data[index].dishTypesLocales![0]!.name!.toString()), // The data i'm getting is "A", "B"
)
)
    }
```